# What is my amazon s3 bucket url? How do I upload many many files to s3 bucket?

Tags: url, amazon-s3, bucket

I'd like to be able to upload a large number of tiny files to amazon s3 bucket using aws CLI with something like this command: `$ time aws s3 cp --recursive --quiet big18v1Pngs https://big18v1.s3.amazonaws.com/`

I got the command from this page: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/getting-the-most-out-of-the-amazon-s3-cli/

I think what I'm struggling with is getting my bucket url?  in the command line when I enter that command I get "error: invalid argument type".  I've attached a picture of my bucket page

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax for the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) S3 copy command is:

```
aws s3 cp local-filename.txt s3://bucket-name/filename.txt
```

There is no need to use `time` -- that was in the article you referenced to output the time that the command took to execute, which is not necessary for your use-case.

See the [`aws s3 cp` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html).

You might also consider using the [`aws s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command that can replicate files and subdirectories, while only copying new/changed files. You could run this on a regular basis to duplicate files to Amazon S3.

```
aws s3 sync directory-name s3://bucket-name/path
```

Comment: Thankyou so much!!!  I'm now uploading my bucket.    Also FYI to other people, I had to add amazonS3FullAccess to my iam user (and then use the aws config command to make it so my ubuntu command terminal could talk to aws: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

Comment: Great! Of course, you don't need to grant "full access" for S3 -- it's good practice to only grant as much access as required (eg just get/upload, not delete; or only for specific buckets), which minimizes potential impacts if credentials are exposed or apps are mis-configured.